# how to set specific avr-gcc include path

Tags: c, gcc, path

Hello my question is how to add specific path to avr-gcc. When I use:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
```

output is:

```
fatal error: LiquidCrystal.h: No such file or directory
```

when I use direct path:

```
#include "/usr/share/arduino/libraries/LiquidCrystal/LiquidCrystal.h"
```

Output is:

```
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/LiquidCrystal/LiquidCrystal.h:5:19: 
fatal error: Print.h: No such file or directory
```

So how to add some specific path to avr-gcc? Thank you. When I run it from Arduino IDE, my code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy all the header files from LiquidCrystal in /usr/include. Then use

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Tell the C preprocessor to look for header files elsewhere: Add `-I/usr/share/arduino/libraries/LiquidCrystal` to the `avr-gcc` compiler command line.

Usually you can add the `-I...` argument to `CPPFLAGS` somewhere in the `Makefile`.

Then

```
#include <LiquidChrystal.h>
```

should work as intended, and when `/usr/share/arduino/libraries/LiquidCrystal/LiquidCrystal.h` tries to `#include <Print.h>`, the C preprocessor will find the `/usr/share/arduino/libraries/LiquidCrystal/Print.h` file.